# ASP.NET MVC elements only on homepage without being in container

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making a website where the homepage has different elements than the other pages, these elements should exist outside the main container in Shared/_Layout.cshtml because they are full width and are not rendered by @RenderBody().

```
// _Layout.cshtml

<div class="only-homepage-element"></div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Everything not rendered by the @RenderBody() will be visible on all pages because they exist on the _Layout.cshtml. How can I place these element only on the homepage and not in the container?

Comment: make a new layout page and inherit from that instead of _Layout

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to find more information about that. If you make that an answer with a little example i'll certainly vote-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to add a section in your `layout.cshtml`

```
// _Layout.cshtml
@RenderSection("topSection", required: false)
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

> By setting required to false, you specify that the section is not required
>   in every view that uses this layout.

and in your homepage view you can add

```
@section topSection{
    <div class="only-homepage-element">
       ...more html
    </div>
}
```